# AWS CDK - Tie Cognito user pool to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I'm trying to set up a pretty basic infrastructure using AWS CDK that consists of

- Cognito user pool
- A lambda
- An Authorizer
- API GW with root and sub path and few methods
- The path which should use the Cognito User Pool as Authorizer

Problem: I don't know how to properly create the Authorizer so it is accepted by API GW

Synthing the CF template works fine, but during deployment I get the following error:

```
Invalid authorizer ID specified. Setting the authorization type to CUSTOM or COGNITO_USER_POOLS requires a valid authorizer.
```

So, seems my Authorizer is not proper enough, even if the creation of the authorizer itself is marked as successful during the deployment.

Any ideas?

Here what I have in code:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda,
    aws_apigateway,
    aws_cognito
)


class PlayGroundStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # Basic lamdba setup
        my_lambda = aws_lambda.Function(
            scope=self,
            id="lambda-1",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_6,
            code=aws_lambda.Code.asset('lambda'),
            handler='hello.handler'
        )

        # Few MethodOptions for the API GW
        my_get_operation = aws_apigateway.MethodOptions(operation_name="GET")
        my_post_operation = aws_apigateway.MethodOptions(operation_name="POST")

        # The API itself
        rest_api = aws_apigateway.LambdaRestApi(
            scope=self,
            id="rest-api-1",
            handler=my_lambda,
            proxy=False,
            default_method_options=my_get_operation
        )

        # User Pool used for auth
        api_userpool = aws_cognito.UserPool(
            scope=self,
            id="user-pool-1",
            sign_in_type=aws_cognito.SignInType.EMAIL
        )

        # The authorizer that should be attached to API GW
        my_cfn_authorizer = aws_apigateway.CfnAuthorizer(
            id='api_authorizer_cfn',
            rest_api_id=rest_api.rest_api_id,
            name='api_authorizer_cfn_name',
            scope=self,
            type='COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
            identity_source='method.request.header.Authorization',
            provider_arns=[api_userpool.user_pool_arn]
        )

        # Set methods for root node
        rest_api.root.add_method(my_get_operation.operation_name)
        rest_api.root.add_method(my_post_operation.operation_name)

        # Create a resource
        my_resource = rest_api.root.add_resource("my_sub_url")
        # And attach the Authorizer
        # This is where I get the error
        my_resource.add_method(http_method="GET",
                               authorization_type=aws_apigateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
                               authorizer=my_cfn_authorizer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You need to set

`authorization_type = my_cfn_authorizer.auth_type`

and that fixes everything. It would've been so much better if they could just tell us to do that in the documentation, but python documentation is scarce.

```py
class PlayGroundStack(core.Stack):

        ...

        # The authorizer that should be attached to API GW
        my_cfn_authorizer = aws_apigateway.CfnAuthorizer(
            id='api_authorizer_cfn',
            rest_api_id=rest_api.rest_api_id,
            name='api_authorizer_cfn_name',
            scope=self,
            type='COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
            identity_source='method.request.header.Authorization',
            provider_arns=[api_userpool.user_pool_arn]
        )

        # Set methods for root node
        rest_api.root.add_method(my_get_operation.operation_name)
        rest_api.root.add_method(my_post_operation.operation_name)

        my_resource = rest_api.root.add_resource("my_sub_url")
        # FIX HERE!!!!!!!
        my_resource.add_method(http_method="GET",
                               authorization_type=my_cfn_authorizer.auth_type, 
                               authorizer=my_cfn_authorizer)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't use string literal to ID field.
The logical id that you provide for each ressource is concatenaed with a hash at run time. In other word, the ID that you see, and the ID that you get are not the same.
[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59070762/12713062)

You have to use getter api to retrieve the ID of your ressource. For example 
rest_api.rest_api_id()

[cdk documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/RestApi.html)